# How to set the default font style for Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

The below screenshot shows a preset list of font styles that are available and show up under the Home tab of the ribbon with Microsoft Word 2010. Notice an orange selection showing that the Normal Style is selected. Whenever I open Microsoft Word, the selection defaults to the 'Normal' Style. How do I set the default style to 'No Spacing' (the style next to 'Normal') every time I open Microsot Word?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open "`normal.dotm`" which should be located in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
```

and set the style you want to use; then save it.

Now restart Word and it should be good.

Comment: It worked!!! To clarify,  If you simply double click normal.dotm, it opens a new word document. You will need to use File > Open, to open normal.dotm.

Comment: @Thomas: That's because `.dotm` files are templates.  You can make any number of these for your standard letter types, and then double click on them to start a new document.