# How can I set a default font in Microsoft Office Word/PowerPoint in Office 2013, on a Windows 10 desktop/laptop?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

How can I set a default font in Microsoft Office Word/PowerPoint in Office 2013, on a Windows 10 desktop/laptop? XP and 7 solutions do not work with Windows 10.
Thank you.

Comment: So  opening `C:\Users\1396172352C\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm` and setting the font does not work? Worked for me when I tried it[.](https://superuser.com/questions/286113/how-to-set-the-default-font-style-for-microsoft-word-2010?rq=1)

Comment: This is for Word: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CustomizeNormalTemplate.htm.

Comment: Also, look into using Theme fonts. Create a Theme with the Body and Heading fonts you want to be using and apply that theme. Here is my writing on Themes in Word. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Themes Here is Faithe Wempen's writing on Themes: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2352175

Answer (score 0):

Change the Dfault Font in **Word**:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-font-in-word-2f50603b-9886-47e4-a483-48ac5ab80163

Change the Dfault Font in **PowerPoint**:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-font-in-powerpoint-8e93c947-c160-4310-8070-afea7da78c33

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to set a default font in PowerPoint, strictly speaking.
It's not an application-wide setting. Each presentation can have its own default font setting.

However, since each presentation is based upon a template, and the template can hold a default font, the trick is to create a template with your specifications and base future presentations on it, and possibly set it as the default template, so new presentations are automatically based on your template.

Comment: Thank you, Steve.